# How to package an application icon properly?

Tags: application-development, icons

There is an blog article on ubuntu developer blog. http://developer.ubuntu.com/2012/02/how-to-prepare-a-compiled-application-for-ubuntu-software-center/

I followed all steps exactly. But the application seems to have no icon when I search it in the dash. The dash displays only blank white icon.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 3):

The `Icon` field in the `.desktop` file, and the file name of the icon file itself, must match. As per the [Icon Naming Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-naming-spec/icon-naming-spec-latest.html), the name should be the same as the application's executable program. It should also be installed in the appropriate sizes, in the appropriate `hicolor` icon theme directory, as per the [Icon Theme Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html).

It seems there is a typo in the page you link to, which says to name the icon as `desktop.png` instead of `dungeon.png`, and it also only talks about installing the single icon, and in the wrong place. This should be considered a bug in the site itself.

If the icons are in the correct place, and still not showing up, it is likely you need to update the icon cache for theme. You can run `sudo gtk-update-icon-cache -f /usr/share/icons/hicolor` to update the system `hicolor` theme directory cache, for example.

Comment: Even if I type the icon name correctly it doesn't appear in the dash or launcher. Very sad. I can use xdg-icon-resource after installing the package but this is a hack.

Comment: Where did you put the icon on the filesystem?

Comment: this is my install

thegame_01/* opt/thegame
hicolor/scalable/apps/thegame.svg usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/thegame.svg
hicolor/64x64/apps/thegame.png usr/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/apps/thegame.png
hicolor/48x48/apps/thegame.png usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/thegame.png
hicolor/32x32/apps/thegame.png usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/thegame.png
thegame.desktop usr/share/applications

Answer (score 2):

To properly install an icon for an application use xdg-icon-resource. The image files must be one of the types: PNG, XPM, or SVG, and the extension must be ".png", ".xpm", or ".svg" (lower case). If a corresponding .icon file exists in the same location as icon-file it will be installed as well.

**For .svg files**

`xdg-icon-resource install --novendor </location/of/your/icon.svg> <icon_name>`.

**For .png and .xpm files**

`xdg-desktop-icon install --size  <16, 22, 32, 48, 64, 128, or 256> </location/of/your/icon.png>  <a_name_you_want>`.

The default icon size launchers and menus use is 48.

Other sources of info:
http://portland.freedesktop.org/xdg-utils-1.0beta1/xdg-icon-resource.html
http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html

Comment: How do you make `xdg-icon-resource` put files in a hierarchy that you're about to package, rather than on the host filesystem?

Comment: I'm afraid `xdg-icon-resource` does not support SVG: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xdg-utils/+bug/790449

Comment: @JackO'Connor: the same way you put binaries and man pages: use `dpkg-buildpackage` or similar packaging script along with the appropriate `dh_*` helpers in your `rules` file, and it will invoke `xdg-icon-resource` for you in a `chroot` when creating the binary package.

Comment: -1: `xdg-desktop-icon` is not for installing icon images in the system, but to install a `.desktop` launcher in the user's _Desktop_. The `-icon` in name is misleading. Also, the suggested `xdg-icon-resource` command simply does not work: `--size` is _required_, and it does not support SVG files at all.