# How can I change the icon of an app launched from keyboard shortcut (or terminal)?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, launcher, icons

I succeeded in changing the poor default icon of NetBeans (32x32), which appears in window switcher (Alt+Tab), to HD one (128x128) when started from Launcher by clicking it, but still unable to make it when launched from a keyboard shortcut ("/bin/sh netbeans") or terminal (just enter "netbeans").

I searched the whole system and replaced every suspicious .png file so I even have no idea where the 32x32 icon comes from. I've also tried modifying "Icon=..." line in .desktop file ([How can I change the icon of an application in the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80627/how-can-i-change-the-icon-of-an-application-in-the-unity-launcher)), "xdg-icon-resource install ..." thing ([How to package an application icon properly?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/277190/how-to-package-an-application-icon-properly)), and alacarte ([How do I add an application to the dash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67753/how-do-i-add-an-application-to-the-dash)), but still fail.

Is there any possible way of doing it? Or, is there any appropriate command of invoking it as if it were clicked from Launcher? (<=> let .desktop to be considered)?

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not positive about this, but I think the icon you're referring to is set by the application itself. Therefore, to change the icon you have to either change it in the program settings (if possible) or alter the program's source code.

I know for a fact that this is how an app I wrote works; I don't know if all are this way, though.

Comment: Thank you a lot. It seems to be impossible to change it in the program settings and I am not enthusiastic enough to alter the source code... so I decided to accept everything.